# Marketo Modules — Invalid Modules

Tags: email-templates, marketo

I'm trying to setup a new email template in the Marketo editor (v.2) and make modules.

However, when I go to save my template in the editor it tells me that my modules are invalid and doesn't save. Even when I scale the template down to basically nothing, once I add any content inside the `container` module, it doesn't work.

Here's my code — can anyone tell me how to set the `container` module properly and why it's throwing an error when I try to save? I've followed the documentation (even though it's not well done) and everything seems like it should be fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" style="width: 100%;">
  <head> 
    <!-- Marketo Variable Definitions --> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="spacerBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="spacerSpacer" mktoname="Height" default="40" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="freeImageBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="freeTextBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="freeTextSpacer" mktoname="Space Before Text" default="40" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="freeTextSpacer2" mktoname="Space After Text" default="40" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="footerBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="footerSpacer" mktoname="Space Before Text" default="10" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="footerSpacer2" mktoname="Space After Text" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="ctaBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="ctaButtonBackgroundColor" mktoname="Button Background Color" default="#333333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="ctaBorderColor" mktoname="Button Border Color" default="#333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="ctaBorderSize" mktoname="Button Border Size" default="1" min="0" max="20" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="ctaSpacer" mktoname="Space Before Button" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="ctaSpacer2" mktoname="Space After Button" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="ctaLink" mktoname="Button Link" default="#" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="ctaLinkText" mktoname="Button Label" default="CALL TO ACTION" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="hrBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="hrBorderColor" mktoname="Border Color" default="" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="hrBorderSize" mktoname="Border Size" default="1" min="0" max="20" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="twoArticlesBackgroundColor" mktoname="Background Color" default="#ffffff" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="twoArticlesButtonBackgroundColor" mktoname="Left Column Button Background Color" default="#333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="twoArticlesButtonBackgroundColor2" mktoname="Right Column Button Background Color" default="#333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="twoArticlesBorderColor" mktoname="Left Column Button Border Color" default="#333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesBorderSize" mktoname="Left Column Button Border Size" default="1" min="0" max="20" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoColor" id="twoArticlesBorderColor2" mktoname="Right Column Button Border Color" default="#333" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesBorderSize2" mktoname="Right Column Button Border Size" default="1" min="0" max="20" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer" mktoname="Space Over Columns" default="40" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer2" mktoname="Left Column Space Below Image" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer3" mktoname="Left Column Space Below Title" default="15" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer4" mktoname="Left Column Space Below Text" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer5" mktoname="Right Column Space Below Image" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer6" mktoname="Right Column Space Below Title" default="15" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer7" mktoname="Right Column Space Below Text" default="20" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoNumber" id="twoArticlesSpacer8" mktoname="Space Below Columns" default="40" min="1" max="300" units="px" step="1" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="twoArticlesLink" mktoname="Left Button Link" default="#" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="twoArticlesLinkText" mktoname="Left Button Label" default="CALL TO ACTION" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="twoArticlesLink2" mktoname="Right Button Link" default="#" /> 
    <meta class="mktoString" id="twoArticlesLinkText2" mktoname="Right Button Label" default="CALL TO ACTION" /> 
    <!-- Other Meta Tags --> 
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" /> 
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" /> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
    <!--[if mso]>
<style type='text/css'>
.primary-font {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]--> 
    <!--[if mso]>
<style type='text/css'>
.secondary-font {
font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
</style>
<![endif]--> 
    <style>
      /*startcommon*/
      @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
        table#boxing{
          width: 100% !important;
        }
      }
      /*endcommon*/
    </style> 
    <!--[if gte mso 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
          #hero .table3-3{
          width: 100% !important;
          }
        </style>
    <![endif]--> 
    <style media="all">
/* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
#outlook a {
  padding: 0;
}
/* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
.ReadMsgBody {
  width: 100%;
}
.ExternalClass {
  width: 100%;
}
/* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
.ExternalClass,
.ExternalClass p,
.ExternalClass span,
.ExternalClass font,
.ExternalClass td,
.ExternalClass div {
  line-height: 100%;
}
/* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
/* iOS BLUE LINKS */
.appleBody a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.appleFooter a {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
}
@-ms-viewport { 
    width: device-width; 
}

</style> 
    <style media="all">
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {

/*starttablet*/

.m_video .mktoVideo tr:first-child img{
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto!important;
  max-height:auto!important;
  min-height:auto!important;
}

body {
  width: auto !important;
}

table[class="table600"] {
  width: 450px !important;
}

table[class="table-inner"] {
  width: 86% !important;
}

table[class="table1-2"] {
  width: 47% !important;
  clear: both;
}

table[class="table1-3"] {
  width: 29.4% !important;
}

table[class="table1-4"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

table[class="table2-3"] {
  width: 64% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

table[class="table3-3"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  clear: both;
}

table[class="footer-logo"] {
  width: 10% !important;
  text-align: right !important;
}

td[class="outer"] {
  min-width: 0 !important;
}

td[class="stack"] {
  padding-bottom: 40px !important;
}

.stack-tablet {
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  float: none !important;
  mso-hide: none !important;
  display: block !important;
}

img[class="mobile-img"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  height: auto !important;
}

td[class="center-tablet"] {
  text-align: center !important;
}

td[class="hide-tablet"] {
  display: none !important;
}

table[class="footer-column"] {
  width: 47% !important;
  text-align: left !important;
}

.m_two-articles .table1-2 {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.m_two-articles .photo img {
  width: 100% !important;
}

.m_two-articles .stack-tablet td {
  height: 60px !important;
}

.m_free-image img {
  width: 450px !important;
}

/*endtablet*/

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {

/*startmobile*/

body {
  width: auto !important;
}

table[class="table600"] {
  width: 290px !important;
}

table[class="table-inner"] {
  width: 80% !important;
  float: none !important;
}

table[class="table1-2"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  clear: both;
}

table[class="table1-3"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  clear: both;
}

table[class="table1-4"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

table[class="table2-3"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

table[class="table3-3"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  clear: both;
}

table[class="footer-logo"] {
  width: 60% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

td[class="outer"] {
  min-width: 0 !important;
}

td[class="td3-1"] {
  width: 60% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.stack-smartphone {
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
  float: none !important;
  display: block !important;
  mso-hide: none !important;
}

td[class="center-smartphone"] {
  text-align: center !important;
}

img[class="mobile-img"] {
  width: 100% !important;
}

td[class="center-tablet"] {
  text-align: center !important;
}

td[class="hide-smartphone"] {
  display: none !important;
}

table[class="footer-column"] {
  width: 100% !important;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.m_free-image img {
  width: 290px !important;
}

.m_hr .table-inner {
  width: 100% !important;
}

/*endmobile*/

}


</style> 
  </head> 
  <body style="margin-bottom: 0; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; padding-bottom: 0; min-width: 100%; margin-top: 0; margin-right: 0; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; margin-left: 0; padding-top: 0; padding-right: 0; padding-left: 0; width: 100%;"> 
    <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; line-height:0;">
      &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
    </div> 
    <!-- Outer table START --> 
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"> 
      <tbody> 
        <tr> 
          <td class="outer" valign="top" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; min-width: 600px; border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #eeeeee;"> 
            <table width="800" align="center" id="boxing" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; border-spacing: 0; border-collapse: collapse;"> 
              <tbody> 
                <tr> 
                  <td class="mktoContainer" id="template-wrapper" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <table width="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="main-nav-breakpoints" style="margin:0 auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" bgcolor="#F2F8FB">
                          <!-- Nav -->
                          <table border="0" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main-nav-breakpoints">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo@2x.png" width="164" height="54" alt="" border="0" align="left" class="logo" style="margin:0; padding:0;"/></a>
                              </td>
                              <td align="right" style="width: 75%; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-align: right; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom; font-style:normal;padding:0px 20px 24px 0px;">
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-one" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">one</a>
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-two" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">two</a>
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-three" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">three</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table><!-- End Nav -->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table><!-- End Header -->
                  </td> 
                </tr> 
              </tbody> 
            </table> 
          </td> 
        </tr> 
      </tbody> 
    </table> 
    <!-- Outer Table END -->  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any modules defined the code you provided. Which sections do you want to be modules?

Answer (score 0):

If your container is a td then all the tables within that TD should be your modules.  And ALL your tables(modules) within that container td need to be marked as a module table by adding class="mktoModule"

Answer (score 0):

According to [Marketo's documentation](http://docs.marketo.com/display/public/DOCS/Email+Template+Syntax#EmailTemplateSyntax-Containers), the type of element's that can have the class "mktoContainer" is a table, tbody, thead, tfoot, or td, and only modules can be inside those elements. If there's anything else present, the container will be considered invalid.

In your HTML, you've defined a td element as the container, but you haven't defined any actual modules within that container. To the table immediately inside your container, you should add the class "mktoModule", a unique id, and the mktoName attribute with a value. Example of changes are below, specifically noting the changes on line 2:

```
                  <td class="mktoContainer" id="template-wrapper" style="-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; mso-table-lspace: 0pt; mso-table-rspace: 0pt; word-break: break-word; -webkit-hyphens: none; -moz-hyphens: none; hyphens: none; border-collapse: collapse;">
                    <table id="module_navigation" mktoName="Navigation" width="630" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" class="main-nav-breakpoints mktoModule" style="margin:0 auto;">
                      <tr>
                        <td width="100%" bgcolor="#F2F8FB">
                          <!-- Nav -->
                          <table border="0" height="100" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="main-nav-breakpoints">
                            <tr>
                              <td style="margin:0; padding:0px 0px 0px 20px;">
                                <a href="#"><img src="images/logo@2x.png" width="164" height="54" alt="" border="0" align="left" class="logo" style="margin:0; padding:0;"/></a>
                              </td>
                              <td align="right" style="width: 75%; padding: 0; font-size: 13px; color: #ffffff; font-weight: normal; text-align: right; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 20px; vertical-align: bottom; font-style:normal;padding:0px 20px 24px 0px;">
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-one" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">one</a>
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-two" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">two</a>
                                  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                                <a href="#" align="right" class="nav-item-three" style="text-decoration: none; color: #003A63;">three</a>
                              </td>
                            </tr>
                          </table><!-- End Nav -->
                        </td>
                      </tr>
                    </table><!-- End Header -->
                  </td>
```

Optionally, you can include the mktoActive and mktoAddByDefault attributes with boolean values to your module.